JQuery Validation conditions for Italian Fiscal Code and VAT number
I'm using the Jquery Validation plugin for my registration form. Users should enter an Italian VAT number ONLY if the company field is filled in, otherwise they should fill in the CF field.
At the same time, I also would like to check if fields entered are correct.
My code is wrong because PI and CF are always required... What is the correct code?


$.validator.addMethod("CodFisc", function(value) {
  var CFControl = /[A-Za-z]{6}[0-9lmnpqrstuvLMNPQRSTUV]{2}[abcdehlmprstABCDEHLMPRST]{1}[0-9lmnpqrstuvLMNPQRSTUV]{2}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9lmnpqrstuvLMNPQRSTUV]{3}[A-Za-z]{1}/;
  return value.match(CFControl);
}, "Enter a correct fiscal code");

$.validator.addMethod("PIva", function(value) {
  var PiControl = /[0-9]{11}/;
  return value.match(PiControl);
}, "Enter a correct VAT number");

$("form#adminForm.form-validate").validate({
  errorClass: 'msgError',
  rules: {
    PI: {
      required: {
        depends: function(element) {
          if ($('#company_field').val() != "") {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }
      },
      PIva: true
    },
    CF: {
      required: {
        depends: function(element) {
          if ($('#company_field').val() == "") {
            return true;
          } else {
            return false;
          }
        }
      },
      CodFisc: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    PI: {
      required: 'Enter a VAT number'
    },
    CF: {
      required: 'Enter a Fiscal Code'
    }
  }
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.20.0/jquery.validate.min.js" ></script>


<form method="post" id="adminForm" name="userForm" action="#" class="form-validate">
  <label class="company" for="company_field">Company</label><input type="text" id="company_field" name="company" size="30" value="" maxlength="64" /><br/>
  <label class="first_name" for="first_name_field">Name *</label><input type="text" id="first_name_field" name="first_name" size="30" value="" class="required" maxlength="32" /><br/>
  <label class="PI" for="PI_field">VAT</label><input type="text" id="PI_field" name="PI" size="50" value="" maxlength="14" /><br/>
  <label class="CF" for="CF_field">Fiscal Code</label><input type="text" id="CF_field" name="CF" size="0" value="" maxlength="16" /><br/>
  <button class="button" type="submit">Register</button>
  </form>




I made a snippet. Please make it a [mcve] - possibly I chose the wrong jQuery validator to add

So what are the rules? Company Name: Not mandatory unless a VAT number is entered first. VAT Number: Visibly required if a company name has been entered.
Fiscal Code (CF): Required only if neither VAT nor company name is provided.

Yes, that is correct!


Changed the regex to make sure the whole value is tested
Added red asterisk if rules are triggered:


Company Name: Not mandatory unless a VAT number is entered first.
VAT Number: required if a company name has been entered.
Fiscal Code (CF): Required only if neither VAT nor company name is provided.

I have decided to refactor to make as DRY as possible.


$(() => {
  // Custom validator methods
  $.validator.addMethod("PIva", function(value, element) {
    const PiControl = /^[0-9]{11}$/;
    return this.optional(element) || PiControl.test(value);
  }, "Please enter a correct VAT number.");

  $.validator.addMethod("CodFisc", function(value, element) {
    const CFControl = /^[A-Za-z]{6}[0-9LMNPQRSTUV]{2}[ABCDEHLMPRST]{1}[0-9LMNPQRSTUV]{2}[A-Za-z]{1}[0-9LMNPQRSTUV]{3}[A-Za-z]{1}$/;
    return this.optional(element) || CFControl.test(value);
  }, "Please enter a correct fiscal code.");

  let isCompanyFilled, isPIFilled, isCFFilled;

  const updateRequirements = () => {
    isCompanyFilled = $("#company_field").is(":filled");
    isPIFilled = $("#PI_field").is(":filled");
    isCFFilled = !isCompanyFilled && !isPIFilled;

    // Update required attributes and asterisks
    $("#company_field").attr("required", isPIFilled);
    $("label[for='company_field'] .label-asterisk").toggle(isPIFilled);

    $("#PI_field").attr("required", isCompanyFilled);
    $("label[for='PI_field'] .label-asterisk").toggle(isCompanyFilled);

    $("#CF_field").attr("required", isCFFilled);
    $("label[for='CF_field'] .label-asterisk").toggle(isCFFilled);
  };

  // Initial check on page load
  updateRequirements();

  // Initialize validation
  const validator = $("#adminForm").validate({
    errorClass: 'msgError',
    rules: {
      company: {
        required: () => isPIFilled
      },
      PI: {
        required: () => isCompanyFilled,
        PIva: true
      },
      CF: {
        required: () => isCFFilled,
        CodFisc: true
      },
      first_name: {
        required: true // Assuming 'Name' is always required as per your form setup
      }
    },
    messages: {
      company: {
        required: "Company name is required since VAT number is entered."
      },
      PI: {
        required: "VAT number is required if a company name is entered."
      },
      CF: {
        required: "Fiscal Code is required when neither VAT number nor company name is provided."
      },
      first_name: {
        required: "Please enter your name."
      }
    }
  });

  // Bind input event to update requirements and validate the form
  $("#company_field, #PI_field").on("input", () => {
    updateRequirements();
    validator.element("#CF_field"); // Re-validate CF field
  });
});
.label-asterisk {
    color: red;
    margin-left: 4px;
    display: none;
  }
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.20.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>


<form method="post" id="adminForm" name="userForm" action="#" class="form-validate">
  <label class="company" for="company_field">Company<span class="label-asterisk">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" id="company_field" name="company" size="30" value="" maxlength="64" /><br/>
  <label class="first_name" for="first_name_field">Name *</label>
  <input type="text" id="first_name_field" name="first_name" size="30" value="" class="required" maxlength="32" /><br/>
  <label class="PI" for="PI_field">VAT<span class="label-asterisk">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" id="PI_field" name="PI" size="50" value="" maxlength="14" /><br/>
  <label class="CF" for="CF_field">Fiscal Code<span class="label-asterisk">*</span></label>
  <input type="text" id="CF_field" name="CF" size="0" value="" maxlength="16" /><br/>
  <button class="button" type="submit">Register</button>
</form>




There are custom selectors built into the plugin that make this part shorter and easier.... return $("#PI_field").is(":filled");

@Sparky I made a few changes ;)
